# Scheduled notification using async storage in React Native

Tags: reactjs, native, asyncstorage, reminders

I want to ask on react native push notification. Right now I am trying to develop a medication reminder application using React Native Expo. Is it possible to achieve where all the input from the user will be stored on async storage with array and it will be scheduled a notification reminder for users to take their medication?